# CSS transform and rotate with animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations, rotatetransform

### HTML

```
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">HELLO</div>
</div>


<div id="div3">
  <div id="div4">HELLO</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#div1
{
position: relative;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
margin: 50px;
padding:10px;
border: 1px solid black;
-webkit-perspective:150px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera  */
perspective:150px;
}

#div2
{
padding:50px;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: red;

-webkit-transform-origin:0%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-transform: rotateY(117deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera  */
transform: rotateX(-75deg);
}




#div3
{
position: relative;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
margin: 50px;
padding:10px;
border: 1px solid black;
-webkit-perspective:150px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera  */
perspective:150px;
}

#div4
{
padding:50px;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: red;

-webkit-transform-origin:0%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera  */
transform: rotateX(-75deg);
}
```

### Trying to do this rotate the inner div from starting position to final position with a delay 2

[Two positions](http://jsfiddle.net/kWC4L/)
   [image: fl]

Code for doing above got it from [Here](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/hands-on-css3/hands-on_3d-transforms.htm) But its not working .What changes to make to make it work

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;

-webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(90deg) rotateY(-90deg);
```

Comment: please explain before negative voting

Comment: when do you want the animation to start? on hovering? or something else?

Comment: On page load i want it start and complete actually this for something else i had created a scroll to div based Menu for portfolio page i want each div to load like a page with flip effect the basic stepping stone for that

Comment: looks like you have to change the HTML code a bit, is that OK? or using script is of course easier.

Comment: I trying to stick to css for this and in worst case with no solution using pure css only i am willing to do it with jquery /javscript there many plugins available to do it I want to implement some things for which this is the basic thing

Comment: check the fiddle http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Azbya

Comment: @krish its not what i am looking for

Comment: @user3127499 the only possible (and also acceptable) solution is try using `animation` and set `animation-fill-mode:forwards`, you have to estimate the most possible time of loading to set the delay for the animation http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/kWC4L/3/ .That's why this may not work expectedly on a client having slow speed network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add *when* to do the animation. I assume that it is upon let's say `hover`.

So, add end styles to `:hover` pseudo-class. And, also specify some transition so that you can see it animating.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/WEX75/4/***

*CSS*:

```
#div1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 50px;
    padding:10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-perspective:150px;
}
#div2 {
    padding:50px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transform-origin:0%;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(117deg);
    transition: 1s all;
}
#div1:hover > #div2 {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

**Edit**: (After reading Op's comments somewhere above)

You want the animation to happen on page load. So, in that case just apply the relevant CSS using jQuery. Wrap that code in domready.

***Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/WEX75/3/***

*JS*:

```
$("#div2").css({
    '-webkit-backface-visibility': 'visible',
    '-webkit-transform-origin': '50% 50%',
    '-webkit-transform': 'perspective(500px) rotateY(0deg)'    
});
```

### Edit 2:

You can introduce a delay of 2s by using `transition-delay: 2s;`.

***Demo 3: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/WEX75/5/***

Comment: good one excellent thanks for pointing out that i hadnt set hover what i tried was this http://jsfiddle.net/WEX75/6/ the problem with this was i properly hovered only this will else it will not work upvote  for your anwser

Comment: @user3127499: Yep, hovering over that thin slice is not for everyone! That's why we hover on the parent.

Comment: really its what resulted in this question being asked

Comment: @user3127499: Yes. Someone downvoted. Must be a rage or revenge or something. :) It happens. Thanks for checking by. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah i think this is the third or fourth time today

Answer (score 2):

Here: **FIDDLE**:  http://jsfiddle.net/9dqAK/12/

**HTML**

```
<div id="stage">
  <div id="spinner">
      hello
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
     from {
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
       -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
     }
     to {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
       -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    }
}

 #spinner {
     -webkit-transform-origin: 150px 0 0;
     -webkit-animation-name: spinner;
     -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-origin: 150px 0 0;
    -moz-animation-name: spinner;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-duration: 6s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    padding:50px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: red;
 }
 #spinner:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  }
```

Comment: upvote for your answer but this is not exactly what i was looking to do but helps in getting another perspective to look into

Answer (score 0):

Add -webkit- to your last transform CSS declaration

Comment: this is the first time i am trying to do some css3 animation and frankly i did not understand what you meant

Comment: In the last line of your provided CSS, you have
`transform: rotateX(-75deg);`

Change that to
`-webkit-transform: rotateX(-75deg);`

Comment: Oh no i forgot remove that i dont want that transform so for testing purpose only what i am trying to implement is till the second last one just like a page flip

Comment: Then the code you have is fine. Make adjustments to the rotateX to show the "completed" transformation. `-webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);`

Comment: answering question and that answer does not amounting to correct  answer attracts a lot of negative vote see here i got negative vote without any explanation why get uneccessary negative vote and loose hard earned reputation points so if you need to point out small mistakes then try to point it out using comments

Comment: I can't add comments. I don't have enough rep points, but thanks for the info.